# VHDL Unable to initialize array of unsigned vectors

Tags: multidimensional-array, vhdl

The lines:

```
type some_array_type is array (0 to 4, 0 to 4) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal some_array : some_array_type := (others=>(others=>'0'));
```

cause vivado 2018.2 to throw the error:

```
[Synth 8-1807] character '0' is not in type unresolved_unsigned
```

for some reason in a VHDL 2008 file. What it the magical syntax to get Vivado to realize that I'm just trying to initialize the array to zeros? I shouldn't have to write a function to do this. I also tried unsigned((others=>(others=>'0')));

The code below can of course be ignored and isn't needed for anything at all. It is just there for the OCD people. "You have to always include a minimal working example!"

```
library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity some_entity is
    port (
        clk, rst: in std_logic ;
    );
end some_entity ;

architecture arch of some_entity is
    type some_array_type is array (0 to 4, 0 to 4) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
    -- throws error
    signal some_array : some_array_type := (others=>(others=>'0'));

    type some_other_array_type is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
    -- doesn't throw error
    signal some_other_array : some_other_array_type(0 to 4) := (others=>(others=>'0'));
begin
    -- some made up process
    process(clk, rst)
        begin
            if(rising_edge(clk)) then
                if rst = '1' then
                    some_array <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
                else
                    some_array <= (others=>(others=>'1'));
                end if;
            end if;
    end process;
end arch;
```

Comment: You have a two dimensional array with elements that are of an array type. You've only covered the two dimensions and not the array elements. The element type of the aggregate is unsigned and not std_ulogic.  To include the elements `(others => (others => (others => '0')))`.  There's also an extra(naneous) declaration separator (semicolon) in the port clause. Likely from  minimization of the code example.

Comment: Yep. That worked. Why not put that as an answer instead of a comment?